# Xcode 6 displaying images on all devices with one storyBoard

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

Im trying to understand how to have different size UiImageViews (not launch images) with only one storyBoard in Xcode 6.
I kind of understand the idea of one abstract storyBoard targeting different devices and understanding how good it is for UIButtons and labels etc.. but Im really confused when it comes to UIImages.

Surley, with all the device sizes you still need different size images for each device ??

For example: lets say I want to have an image of a flower (flower.png) as a backGround on all devices.

So previously, I would have 2 storyBoards - one for iPhone and one for iPad.

The iphone storyBoard would display the following images:
iPhoneFlower.png (480 x 320)
iPhoneFlower@2x.png (960 x 640)

and the iPad storyBoard would display the following images:
iPadFlower.png (1024 x 768)
iPadFlower@2x.png (2048 x 1536)

I just can't see how you can now place an image in the large square abstract storyBoard and the then set AutoLayout and size classes to target the an image to display correctly on all devices (without cropping or stretching) ??

yea I know this  is probably a stupid question but because its so different to how I have previously worked, I'm just not getting it. I thought about setting up a storyBoard for each device but that seems like a step backwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To choose the different images automatically on different devices, use the asset catalog, which allows you to set up this distinction. Now one image view in the storyboard will get the right image on each device type.

That might be all you need, because if you use constraints that position the image view without sizing it, the image view will automatically adopt the size of the image.

If you *do* need to size the image view explicitly with constraints, use Size Classes in the storyboard. Now your constraints can be conditional on the size classes of the actual runtime environment. The iPhone has a compact width (horizontal size class); the iPad doesn't.

Comment: @ matt - Thanks Matt for putting me in the right direction. I thought the asset catalog was for icons and launch images only. Best I start learning more about the asset catalog!

Comment: The asset catalog is even more important in iOS 8 and the iPhone 6 Plus because now you've got _three_ image sizes to deal with. You can use the asset catalog or you can go crazy. :)

Comment: Already asset catalogs seem amazing and very logical. Yes, I was nearly going crazy to work with image sizes for all devices. I was actually trying to do it all programatically. Thanks again.